# Angular JS Passing Multiple Arrays to scope.list

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two requests for two separate JSON file. I am trying to pass them to the scope but I got the [ngRepeat dupes error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes).

Here is my controller:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize']);
app.controller('myController',
    function ($scope, $http, $sce) {
        var request = {
            method: 'get',
            url: 'scripts/data.json',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json"
        };

        var requestMenu = {
            method: 'get',
            url: 'scripts/menu.json',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json"
        };

        $scope.arrBirds = new Array;
        $scope.arrMenu = new Array;

        $http(request, requestMenu)
            .success(function (jsonData) {
                $scope.arrBirds = jsonData;
                $scope.arrMenu = jsonData;
                $scope.list = $scope.arrBirds + $scope.arrMenu;
            })
            .error(function () {

            });
    });
```

Comment: can you add your HTML code ? and you need to use .concat method for merging two arrays, you are using + ?

Comment: Try $scope.list = $scope.arrBirds.concat($scope.arrMenu);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make two $http requests and merge their data, use `$q.all`:

```
app.controller('myController', function ($scope, $http, $q) {
    var request = {
        method: 'get',
        url: 'scripts/data.json',
    };

    var requestMenu = {
        method: 'get',
        url: 'scripts/menu.json',
    };

    $scope.arrBirds = new Array;
    $scope.arrMenu = new Array;

    var promise1 = $http(request);
    var promise2 = $http(requestMenu);

    $q.all([promise1, promise2]).then([response1,response2] => {
        $scope.arrBirds = response1.data;
        $scope.arrMenu =  response2.data;
        $scope.list = $scope.arrBirds.concat($scope.arrMenu);
    })
});
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $q Service API Reference - $q.all](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all)
- [MDN JavaScript Reference - Array.prototype.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

Answer (score -1):

You can use angular.extend(dest, src1, src2,...);
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend

Comment: May I know why it got down rated?